# Syntax error unexpected '}' while writing HTML within PHP tags

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write HTML code within a PHP file and getting the syntax error:

> unexpected '}'

I don't know I missed something or not.

Here is my code:

```
$html = '
<p><strong>About:</strong><br>
    '.$about.'
</p>
<strong>Education:</strong><br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Degree</th>
            <th>Institute</th>
            <th>Start Year</th>
            <th>End Year</th>
        </tr>
        '.$querySkills="select * from skills where user_id = $userId";

        $runSkills=mysqli_query($db,$querySkills);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($runSkills)) {
            '<tr>
             <td>'.$row["degree_title"].'</td>
             <td>'.$row["institute"].'</td>
             <td>'.$row["startyear"].'</td>
             <td>'.$row["endyear"].'</td>
             </tr>
             '.}.'

    </table>
';
```

Comment: you are missing '.' after '{'.... just after opening while loop...

Comment: And you can't concat strings like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code is too wrong to explain why this is wrong. An example that should work:

```
$html = '
<p><strong>About:</strong><br>'.$about.'</p>
 <strong>Education:</strong><br>
      <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Degree</th>
    <th>Institute</th>
    <th>Start Year</th>
    <th>End Year</th>
    </tr>
';

$querySkills = "select * from skills where user_id = $userId";

$runSkills=mysqli_query($db,$querySkills);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($runSkills)) {
    $html .= '<tr>
        <td>'.$row["degree_title"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["institute"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["startyear"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["endyear"].'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
}

$html .= '</table>';
```

Try using an IDE such as NetBeans or [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm), which will highlight syntax errors while you're typing.

Comment: It's not "too wrong to explain". It's always possible to explain. Plus it's a duplicate question.

Comment: thanks, that's solved my problem